# Docker won't start up on ubuntu 16.04.01

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to install docker on ubuntu version 16.04.01, it gave an error after install that there were errors with package docker-engine. And when i try to start the docker service via the command docker daemon -D
I get this log:

```
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 999
DEBU[0000] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 6517
DEBU[0000] libcontainerd: containerd connection state change: TRANSIENT_FAILURE
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=65536
DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
DEBU[0000] containerd: supervisor running                cpus=2 memory=4096 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir=/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd
DEBU[0000] containerd: grpc api on /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock
DEBU[0001] Using default logging driver json-file
DEBU[0001] Golang's threads limit set to 1855710
DEBU[0001] [zfs] zfs command is not available: exec: "zfs": executable file not found in $PATH
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.
DEBU[0001] Using graph driver vfs
DEBU[0001] Max Concurrent Downloads: 3
DEBU[0001] Max Concurrent Uploads: 5
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support oom control.
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support memory swappiness.
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit.
WARN[0001] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
WARN[0001] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
WARN[0001] mountpoint for pids not found
DEBU[0001] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

I am using a server hosted by another company and this is a preinstalled version of ubuntu, i've tried reinstalling it multiple times and doing it all over again but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Update package information, ensure that APT works with the https method, and that CA certificates are installed.

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

Add the new GPG key.

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
```

Add an entry for your Ubuntu operating system in docker.list:

`$ vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` (did not exist)

content:

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

and save (:wq)

Update the APT package index.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Purge the old repo if it exists (previous installations).

```
$ sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker
```

Verify that APT is pulling from the right repository.

```
$ apt-cache policy docker-engine
```

Update your package manager.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install the recommended package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Install Docker.

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Start the docker daemon.

```
$ sudo service docker start
```

Verify docker is installed correctly.

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

additional: you can create a docker group.
Source of my answer: [the official documentation of docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/).

Comment: Yes this is the guide that i've followed to install, however when i run: sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) i get the message that it could not find any packages via regex for : 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-042stab116.2'

Comment: That's an odd kernel release string. I think `4.4.0-34` is the current xenial release.

Comment: Now it says that there where errors during the processing packages: linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic, linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic and docker-engine